# separate Preview resource files in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, preview

Is it possible to use separate `Preview` resources in jetpack compose, let's say a different strings file or manifest?

Comment: How does this have no answers yet? I would like to know if there is a best practice for this.